# How to run ionic 1 app with scss on ionic 3 cli

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I have a project which was developed in ionic 1. now we need to deploy it and i am trying to build on ionic 3 cli.

Because of the version mismatches in `ionic-cli`, the scss styles are not working. From the code I can see that in ionic 1, scss was used for styling.
These styles are not loading when trying to run ionic serve or build and see in simulator.

I have tried:

```
ionic serve --v1
ionic build ios --v1
```

just to check if such a flag works. it doesn't.

How can I build ionic 1 project which used scss on ionic 3 cli?

Comment: with ref: [link] (https://codepen.io/leob6/post/quick-tip-using-gulp-to-customize-the-serve-run-and-build-process-for-your-ionic-framework-apps)
`guld default`
then
`ionic serve`
its working but when i build and run in simulator its showing white screen only. any help?

Answer (score 1):

answer is easier. in another terminal run

> gulp sass

before ionic serve or ionic build ios

earlier i was using gulp default which wasn't working.